# Zyre.js in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am currently trying to work with zyre.js in my project. I tried to npm install zyre.js and it added itself to the node_modules folder in my project. When I tried to run my application after installing this, I got no error. After adding the line const Zyre = require('zyre.js'); I get the following: The development server returned response error code:500 unable to resolve module 'events' from  C:\Users\User\Desktop\GitHub...\node_modules\zyre.js\lib\zyre.js ... 
I cannot seem to get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does import Zyre from "zyre" show the same error?

Comment: Should i uninstall zyre from my node_modules folder first then just add an import statement?

Comment: I would uninstall the module, install it again and then try with import.

Comment: I npm uninstall zyre.js and tried to run my project again with success. I reinstall zyre.js (npm install zyre.js) and run my project with success. I added the import statement: import { Zyre } from 'zyre'; and it gives the same error when i tried to require zyre.js from the original problem

Comment: I know links are not a helpful response but maybe this will be helpful : https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/721 
I do use react-native, but I have never seen this error since I am a Linux user, hope this can help.

Comment: Just an update... I have decided to move away from using zyre and am now using react-native-wifi-p2p. This will work the same way i wanted zyre to work. The only downfall is that it is not cross platform and I have not found any react native libraries for cross platform peer to peer functionality